# Does reapplying Hex cost a spell slot?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-slots, duration

The PHB for the spell "Hex" indicates that (5e)

> If the target drops to 0 hit points before this spell ends, you can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to curse a new creature.

Does this mean I am expending another spell slot during my bonus action to curse a new target, or am I simply "commanding" the spell to move? If it doesn't expend a spell slot, does the duration reset to 1 hour for the new creature, or does the duration apply to when it was initially cast on the first creature?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The answer lies in the text you've quoted:

> If the target drops to 0 hit points **before this spell ends**, you can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to curse a new creature.

So when you move the *Hex*, the spell hasn't ended. It's still an ongoing spell, meaning that you don't need to recast it and the duration doesn't change - all you're doing is moving the effect of the spell around.