# Does Hex end early if there are no more targets?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

At our table we had a discussion about the spell Hex and its duration. The way it's written it appears to us that if there is no creatures for it to bounce to the spell should end, regardless of its duration. Is that how it should function?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From Hex's stat block:

> **Duration:** Concentration, up to 1 hour

Therefore, even if there is no creature to bounce to, Hex lasts as long as the Warlock concentrates on the spell for up to 1 hour. If there are no creatures left to bounce to, a Warlock can continue to concentrate on the spell until a new one enters his range and use his bonus action to apply the Hex to the new target.

Higher level Warlocks can maintain concentration on the Hex for longer periods as noted under "At Higher Levels" in the spell description:

> ***At Higher Levels.*** When you cast this spell using
>   a spell slot of 3rd or 4th level, you can maintain your
>   concentration on the spell for up to 8 hours. W hen you
>   use a spell slot of 5th level or higher, you can maintain
>   your concentration on the spell for up to 24 hours.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not the spell bounces to anyone, the duration does not change. Also, that was pretty much lined out in ["Does reapplying Hex cost a Spell Slot?"](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59509/does-reapplying-hex-cost-a-spell-slot).