# Can You Recast Hunter's Mark Whenever You Want?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

[*Hunter's mark*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunters-mark) states the following:

> If the target drops to 0 hit points before this spell ends, you can
>   use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to mark a new
>   creature.

Does that mean that if the target drops to 0 and combat ends then starts again within the hour, you can mark a new target?

Comment: Heavily related: "[Does Hex end early if there are no more targets?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59809)"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes (although it's "retarget" more than "recast")

You've quoted the relevant line. It's "a subsequent turn", not "the next turn" or "a subsequent turn as long as its within X amount of time" or anything of the sort. Note that Hunter's Mark requires concentration though, so it's only really an 1 hour if you get hit very infrequently (or not at all) or otherwise get very lucky on your concentration checks (and don't use any other spells that require concentration in the meantime).

Note that you're not "recasting" it in the sense that you're not actually casting a spell when you choose a new target, this matters because for instance this doesn't trigger Mage Slayer attacks and isn't interruptible by Counterspell.

Comment: In case you wanted to mention it, the fact that it doesn't take a spell slot is supported in this question: "[Does eapplying Hex cost a spell slot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59509)"

Comment: Also worth noting that when upcasting, the spell lets you maintain concentration even longer - up to 8 hours, then up to 24 hours.