# Does the Hunter's Mark spell chain to multiple creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

I'm looking to play a ranger. The Hunter's Mark spell says:

> If the target drops to 0 hit points before this spell ends. you can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to mark a new creature.

Does that mean I can keep marking a new enemy each time the last one dies until the hour's up?

Comment: I asked a question about Hex that has a similar mechanic; it may be helpful to you: [Does reapplying Hex cost a spell slot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59509/does-reapplying-hex-cost-a-spell-slot)

Answer (score 20):

First, this is a concentration spell, if your concentration breaks (p.203 PHB) the spell ends. It is also time limited - you can concentrate for up to 1 hour (1st or 2nd level slot), 8 hours (3rd or 4th level slot) or 24 hours (5th+ level slot).

Second, it does exactly what it says:

> If the target drops to 0 hit 
>   points before this spell ends, you can use a bonus action 
>   on a subsequent turn of yours to mark a new creature.

So if a creature drops to 0 hit points and you keep concentrating then on a subsequent turn of yours (which can be in a completely different encounter 45 minutes later) you can use your bonus action to mark a new creature. And so on and so forth until the end of the spell.

Comment: Note that the spell explicitly limits its duration to 1 hour; you can concentrate to get up to 1 hour duration, but not more than that.

Comment: @ObliviousSage Unless you use a 3rd+ level spell slot to cast it (though that's probably not a very efficient thing to do for a ranger).

Comment: This also means that if the PC used a reaction to do something else, they cannot re-apply hunters mark, correct?

Comment: Not correct for 2 reasons, 1. On your turn you get to move, take an action and 1 bonus action if available  - you also have 1 reaction to take on your or anyone else's turn: bonus action and reaction are different things, 2. Even if you used your bonus action on this turn, you can use the bonus action on the next turn (or the one after that, or 10 from now, or any turn before the spell expires) to choose another target.