# Does moving the curse from the Hex spell to a new target have any spell components?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, spell-components

Casting the *Hex* spell initially requires a verbal, somatic, and material component. For the duration (concentration up to 1, 8, or 24 hours depending on spell level), if something dies while hexed, I can use a bonus action to apply it to a different creature.

**Does reapplying *Hex* to a new target (after the previous one is reduced to 0 HP) have a verbal, somatic, or material component?**

I am wondering whether or not it would be obvious that I was reapplying the spell to another target or if I would have to try and hide it. I could, in theory, kill something I've hexed and then several hours later sneakily apply the spell's disadvantage on an ability check to a creature and he would never know (or his friends would never know).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. The components of the spell are only required at the point it is cast. Beyond that moment, the warlock need only maintain concentration to keep the spell active, gaining the ability to shift the spell on a subsequent turn after the current target has died. In essence, the warlock isn't 'reapplying' Hex; instead, the spell is maintained through concentration and the warlock shifts the focus of his ire to another target after the first has died. Mechanically, this is done on one of the warlocks subsequent turns through the use of his bonus action. This is similar effect to the Ranger spell, [Hunter's Mark](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63158/does-hunters-mark-chain-to-multiple-creatures).

Relevant text from *Hex:*

> If the target drops to 0 hit points before this spell ends, **you can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to curse a new creature.** (PHB p.251, emphasis mine)

Answer (score 7):

No, you are not casting the spell again, just maintaining concentration.

On a broader note, in general, even if you were casting the spell that does not necessarily mean that the victim knows you cast a spell or that they were the target. See [Is a creature aware that a Hex or Hunter's Mark spell has been cast on it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64549/is-a-creature-aware-that-a-hex-or-hunters-mark-spell-has-been-cast-on-it/64550#64550)