# Can you choose a different ability for Hex when changing its target?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

As a corollary to "[Does reactivating Hex have any spell Components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72738/does-reactivating-hex-have-any-spell-components)," is the player allowed to choose a different ability when cursing a new creature as a bonus action? RAW, it reads as a no, but a RAI argument could support a yes.

The warlock isn't recasting Hex after the initial contact dies; instead, he maintains concentration on the spell and shifts the focus of the spell to a new target via a bonus action on a subsequent turn. The spell doesn't say it must be shifted on *the* subsequent turn following the death of the target. Rather, it may be moved on *a* subsequent turn. Relevant text of Hex follows:

> **Also, choose one ability when you cast the spell.** [...] If the target drops to 0 hit points before this spell ends, you can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to curse a new creature. (PHB p.251, emphasis mine)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### No, you can't

You have answered your own question. I understand what you say by RAI could possibly support a "YES", but the RAW clearly does not. You choose how you want the hex to work when you cast it.

> Also, Choose one ability when you cast the spell.

The bonus action to move it to a new creature simply moves the hex and doesn't allow or state that you can alter the terms of your Hex.

Comment: Short any 5e errata, I suspect this is the answer. Posted the new question with the intention of answering, rather than including it as a tangent to the answer on the linked question.

Comment: As an aside, while not technically allowed by the rules, it wouldn't be unreasonable or a significant boost to the spells strength for a DM to allow a change of affected ability when you re-target the spell.