# Can Hunter's Mark be moved after Silence has been cast on a character?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components, spellcasting

Situation:

In a battle sequence our Paladin (Oath of Vengeance) has successfully cast Hunter's mark, later in the battle our Wizard cast Silence.

We know that Hunter's Mark requires V (verbal) component to cast, but is it also required to "Move" the spell?  Can the paladin move the "Hunter's mark" to a new target when he has been silenced?

Comment: Related on Hex: [Does reapplying Hex have any spell components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72738/33707)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Yes it can be moved

Moving [Hunter's Mark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunters-mark) is not casting the spell again and simply requires a bonus action:

> If the target drops to 0 hit points before this spell ends, you can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to mark a new creature.

The spell only needs to be cast once (note that the spell never ends during this process), then as long as concentration is maintained, only a bonus action is needed to mark a new creature. This means that the act of moving is not casting and does not require anything else, including components, so it is not affected by silence.