# If I trigger something on my turn, can I immediately take my Action to react?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, reactions

*Alberich the Absent-minded is moving towards the evil lich Xanax to put a leather bag over its head. Xanax' skeleton minion attacks him in passing with an opportunity attack. Alberich has not used his action yet. He stops his movement to cast a quick [mage armor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mage-armor) on himself, which he forgot to do in the morning.*

It is not only about opportunity attacks. Other triggers would be possible, for example:

*Alberich is moving away from Xanax as a 10-foot pit opens beneath his feet. He has not used his action yet, and defly casts [dimension door](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door) to get away before dropping into the pit trap.*

Would this be possible? If not, why not?

(The question is not about being able to take the Ready action that allows you to take a premeditated Action in response to a trigger. It is clear that you can do that. It is about spontaneously deciding to take the Action.)

Comment: When I told my doctor I get nervous on airplanes, I did not intend for him to prescribe me a lich as a chaperone.

Comment: I may be missing something, but this seems to be a very meandering way of asking "If I trigger an opportunity attack, can I immediately use my action to cast Mage Armor and prevent that attack?"

Comment: This scenario can be answered within reading the first few lines without much ambiguity or interpretation required. About 90% of the text of the question is irrelevant regarding using actions during reactions. The question being asked in the body is "Can I take an action during an enemy reaction" or "What prevents me from taking an action here" rather than the title of the entirety to "when can actions be used"

Comment: I concur with @Raj.  This question would be much clearer if it succinctly stated what it was asking up front and followed with an example.  I think the suggested wording by Raj is very clear.

Comment: With the edits to this question, it's expanded from, "can i take an action in response to a reaction or OOA" to "if I trigger something that isn't *technically* a reaction which would normally be solved by using a reaction, can I use an action as a response." The only example given though is still involving an OOA. Can we get some other examples to look at to actually make this not about reaction interactions?

Comment: This question is interesting and the answers just raise more questions!

Comment: [Related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/196835/when-can-you-use-a-bonus-action) that caused this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You cannot take an action while a reaction is resolving, as defined within the "Reactions" definition (PHB.190).

All we need is the first paragraph. (Emphasis mine)

> Xanax' skeleton minion attacks him in passing ***with an opportunity attack***.

An opportunity attack is a reaction of the skeleton, described in the PHB.190 the pertinent line regarding reactions:

> If the reaction **interrupts another creature's turn**, that creature **can continue** its turn **right after** the reaction.

(While *can* is not a *must*, it implies a cannot prior to the condition being met)

Actions can only be performed during your own turn, reactions can occur any time they are triggered, but **specific beats general** allowing some reactions to interrupt your turn.

So you cannot continue your turn to take an action until after the reaction is finished. The exception being to use your own reaction to react so long as you have one to use that has been triggered.

Simple solution to this scenario, remember to cast mage armor shortly after heading out for the adventuring day. Otherwise, if Shield is prepared, that is a reaction spell that could be used.

Comment: I think it's somewhat of a logical leap from "after the reaction the creature can continue its turn" to "that means you can't interrupt the reaction with your action" - I mean you even point out that you COULD interrupt the reaction with your own reaction. Your interpretation of the word "can" and its implications is doing a LOT of heavy lifting in your argument. If the rules says "that creature continues its turn right after the reaction" then I think your argument would be so much stronger, unfortunately they don't' say that.

Comment: I strongly disagree. There is no logical leap here, the word choice was specific and pulled directly from the PHB. "can" here is giving the option to stop or continue your turn after being interrupted, regardless of your choice, it occurs AFTER the reaction. Your second point suggesting that reactions cannot interrupt other reactions is just plain wrong. Interrupting reactions is 100% a function of some reactions in the case of counter-spell chains, in any case, the reaction will define when it triggers. Shield is listed as an example. Please support your assertion that these are not the case.

Comment: I agree that reactions can interrupt reactions, but I think you don't do justice to this contradiction of the assertion that you cannot do things during a reaction. If you assert that you can't take "your turn" during a reaction, you should explain why reactions are an exception to this. The logical leap is from "when the reaction is done you continue your turn" to "you can't do anything during a reaction". There's some kind of step missing in between - why can't you take an action during the reaction then later continue your turn? It's not explained.

Comment: "**If the reaction interrupts another creature's turn**, that creature **can continue its turn right after** the reaction." Emphasis mine. Notice that it states **specifically**, that the option to continue one's turn occurs "right after the reaction." Were there an option to continue one's turn (to take an action) during or before the reaction, it would be stated. We see though, that it is Not. Actions can only be performed during your own turn, reactions can occur any time they are triggered.
"You can use it right after I'm done using it" is to say, You can't use it until then

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your argument is that during a reaction it's not "your turn" anymore? If so could you please spell this out in the answer and discuss any potential ramifications of this ruling (one example would be a rogue using their reaction to interrupt a reaction to deal sneak attack damage despite having already used sneak attack damage on their turn)?

Comment: The point is that the reaction interrupts your turn (specific beats general) and must be resolved before your turn can continue. allowing you to take an action. I've done the defining in the answer. I'd appreciate the same extent in return in your rogue example, as I've read discussions on how reactions can be used specifically to give rogues more sneak attacks per turn, not that it relates to op's question. A chat can be created if must be

Comment: Understandable, but like I said I wonder if there's any other interesting situations this ruling would create. The example that jumped out to me would be something like a Battle Master 2 / Rogue 1 fighting a goblin, the BM/R moves away from the goblin provoking an OA, the goblin misses and the BM/R uses riposte to attack the goblin, dealing damage with sneak attack. Then the BM/R moves back to the goblin and attacks again with sneak attack. This effectively doubles the DPR of the BM/R by sneak attacking twice. I wonder if there are other situations that arise from this ruling.

Comment: The point is that the reaction interrupts your turn (specific beats general) and must be resolved before your turn can continue, allowing you to take an action. No claim was made that your turn has ended or that it's not your turn. I've done the defining in the answer. I'd appreciate the same extent in return in your rogue example, as I've read discussions on how reactions can be used specifically to give rogues more sneak attacks per turn, not that it relates to op's question. A chat can be created if must be.

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to clarify, I thought you were saying that since the reaction interrupts your turn it's not "your turn" anymore so you can't take actions. It seems in your latest reply you are saying that it is indeed still your turn but you can't take actions? In which case your logic "Actions can only be performed during your own turn" ... "so you cannot continue your turn to take an action until after the reaction is finished." doesn't quite follow.

Comment: That's why I edited the title of my answer a while back.  https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/ag1klg/sneak_attack_and_riposte_question/ here is a discussion on that combination. RAW, it appears to allow the rogue to get a sneak attack once during any turn, including other players. There is no limit on sneak attacks per round AFAIK.

Comment: I believe this is a slightly different situation. It's normal for a rogue to sneak attack twice per round by attacking once on their turn and then fishing for OAs (or some other method). I'm suggesting that using (what I thought was) your ruling that during a reaction it's not your turn to use riposte to deal sneak attack damage - combined with a normal attack that lets you sneak attacking twice before ending your turn. This is fairly different to sneak attacking twice - once on your turn and once on someone else's.

Comment: Just noticed where I could clarify better in the answer. Editted the body to clarify that it's still your turn, some reactions can interrupt it temporarily. Also, I'm too new to figure out how to start a chat, but there's a button here that appeared, so I'm pushin it to move it to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135013/discussion-between-danger-lake-and-non-novelist).

Answer (score -1):

### You cannot take an Action while moving or taking another Action

The last rule you quote is quite clear about that: “You can break up your movement on your turn, using some of your speed before and after your action.”

Alberich is moving when subjected to the opportunity attack (because that is what triggered the skeleton’s reaction), therefore, he cannot take an action until he finishes moving which will be after the skeleton’s reaction is resolved.

More generally, since reactions are “instant”, they must be fully resolved before any further movement or actions by the character whose turn it is.

Comment: I agree, but since movement can specifically be 'broken up', I think you could state 'he cannot take an action until he _finishes_ moving' a little more clearly.  That is, it is possible to move, act, and then move more - so why would that not work in the case the OP presents?

Comment: What rule are you talking about and what part of it do you think specifically disallows this?

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question directly, your action is your turn.

As you pointed out, in the [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#YourTurn), it says:

> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed and **take one action**. You decide whether to move first or take your action first. Your speed--sometimes called your walking speed--is noted on your character sheet.
>
> **The most common actions you can take are described in the Actions in Combat section**. Many **class features and other abilities provide additional options** for your action.

The list of Actions in Combat: Attack, Cast a spell, Dash, Disengage, Dodge, Help, Hide, Ready, Search, and Use an object. It does mention class features and abilities can give a character more choices, but for that, you would need to find something specific to a class.

The paragraph also says, "most common". This is because it is not an inclusive list. There will be actions a character can take that don't fall into one of the listed headings. An example is talking. It does not appear on the list, but it is definitely something a character can do. It's up to the DM to decide if it requires a full action or can be part of something else.

[Reaction](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Reactions) is the term for reacting to a trigger. However, it does not appear on the list of possibilities of an Action.

> Certain special abilities, spells, and situations allow you to take a special action called a reaction. A reaction is an instant response to a trigger of some kind, which can occur on your turn or on someone else's. The opportunity attack, described later in this section, is the most common type of reaction.

Reactions only happen due to special abilities, spells, and situation. Since it is a named course of action (lower case), like Bonus Action, I would consider it not available during an Action.

### There is an in-between

You can [Ready](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Ready) an Action (appears on the list):

> Sometimes you want to get the jump on a foe or wait for a particular circumstance before you act. To do so, you can take the Ready action on your turn, which lets you act using your reaction before the start of your next turn.

You use your Action to prepare for a trigger and use a Reaction. But that becomes your Action.

But Readying has its own problems. You have to declare what the trigger is and what you will do in response to that trigger before hand.

So Alberich could have said something like, "I'm going to walk towards Xanax, but if any of its minions start to attack me, I'll cast *mage armor*."

Now we have another problem. If your readied Action is casting a spell, you have to cast it as your Action. Then hold it, as if it was a Concentration spell, until the trigger happens.

> When you ready a spell, you cast it as normal but hold its energy, which you release with your reaction when the trigger occurs. To be readied, a spell must have a casting time of 1 action, and holding onto the spell's magic requires concentration.

So in your scenario, Alberich has to have cast the *mage armor* spell to begin with. More over, if the trigger does not occur, the spell energy is not released so they have wasted the spell.

But Alberich shouldn't feel bad. Melee classes lose out when they use the Ready Action. Since the Attack Action doesn't happen on their turn, as pointed out [in this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/123520/38834), where the character would normally get multiple attacks, their Readied Attack Action is reduced to a single attack (similar to an Attack of Opportunity).

All in all, Alberich is going to get hit. And if they survive, maybe they'll make a checklist.

Comment: I don't feel like it's a strong argument to say "reactions can do this therefore actions can't". You say "Actions are based on the player's choices." so why can't the player choose to take an action during a move or during a bonus action or during an opponent's reaction? Why can't that be the player's choice? The argument seems super shaky here, even if I think your conclusion is ultimately correct.

Comment: @Non-humanPerson, I agree. It required a bit of inferring. I rewrote the beginning on a more stable premise.

Answer (score -3):

## The answer is easy, but complex. It depends

If the player announced that he moves to put the bag over his head, he would be using his action to 'Use an Item'. (basis of combat section 5e PHB) If he said he was moving to the lich, but never said why, and was already holding the bag, then it could be seen that he has not used his action.

HOWEVER. He can still have his reaction, as you get one reaction per combat cycle (from the beginning of your turn to the beginning of your next turn)

I hoped this helped

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).